# Clone bits by range by bitwise ops on C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How i can clone range of bits from one variable to another?

For example, i have

```
dec =  decimal 49280, binary 11000000 10000000
dec2 = decimal 445,   binary       01 10111101
```

How can i clone 6 LSB bits from variable `dec2` to `dec`?

After this operation I need to clone next 4 bits from `dec2` to `dec` but in a start of 2nd byte? (from 9th least significant bit) (`dec` is like a "mask").

The desired behavior is:

```
dec =  11000000 10000000
dec2 =       01 10111101
res1 = 11000000 10111101
res2 = 11000110 10111101
```

Comment: "from the end" - what does this mean? To prevent confusion, we typically use the names MSB (most significant bit) and LSB (least significant bit).

Comment: Also, the question would be clearer if you asked to do only one "bit-cloning" operation. If you know how to do one, you will know how to do two. Or if there are two very different operations, show the desired result of the first one, and then the final desired result.

Comment: @anatolyg it's means LSB,thanks!

Comment: 192 dec is not `11000000 10000000` but `11000000`, what do you mean?

Comment: I didn't understand anything. Please elaborate with some ascii art.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ops,sorry one sec please

Comment: @anatolyg thanks a lot!....

Comment: http://rextester.com/OEKBO57718 ? I don't post this as answer cause, Your question is not accurate enough.

Comment: @Stargateur nicely done, need time to deal with it.
Sry for this poorly worded question, and thanks anatolyg for help with formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualize bitwise operations if you replace example bit values by letters:

```
dec =  abcdefghijklmnop
dec2 = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
```

First, extract the needed bits from dec2, and replace all the rest with zeros:

```
tmp2 = dec2 & 0b0000000000111111;
```

Here I am using a binary literal with `0b` prefix; if your compiler doesn't support it, use an equivalent hexadecimal literal (like `0x3f`).

```
first operand:  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
second operand: 0000000000111111
result:         0000000000KLMNOP
```

Then replace the target bits with zeros:

```
tmp1 = dec & 0b1111111111000000;

first operand:  abcdefghijklmnop
second operand: 1111111111000000
result:         abcdedghij000000
```

Finally, do a bitwise OR:

```
res1 = tmp1 | tmp2;

first operand:  abcdedghij000000
second operand: 0000000000KLMNOP
result:         abcdefghijKLMNOP
```

This is a widely used property of the bitwise-OR operation - if one of its inputs is zero, it copies the other to the output.

---

For your second operation, you will need a bitwise shift. Without getting into the details of which bits you need, you can still use the visualization technique with the letters:

```
temp = (dec2 & 0b0000001111000000) << 2;

dec2 =             ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
second operand:    ......1111......
after bitwise AND: ......GHIJ......
after shift left:  ....GHIJ........
```

Here I used a dot `.` to represent a zero bit.